# object with type qualifiers are not compatible with the member function

Tags: c++, function, class, return-type

I was making a ray tracer and in the header it gave me this error c++ in the header file. It has to do with the perlin_interp return. Help me please! thanks

the two errors:

Error   C2662   'double perlin::perlin_interp(vec3 [][2][2],double,double,double)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const perlin' to 'perlin &' RayTracer   c:\users\graha\source\repos\raytracer\perlin.h  57

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1086   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "perlin::perlin_interp" RayTracer   C:\Users\graha\source\repos\RayTracer\perlin.h  57

```
#include "vec3.h"
#include "rtweekend.h"
#include <random>


inline double trilinear_interp(double c[2][2][2], double u, double v, double w) {
    auto accum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                accum += (i*u + (1 - i)*(1 - u))*
                (j*v + (1 - j)*(1 - v))*
                (k*w + (1 - k)*(1 - w))*c[i][j][k];

    return accum;
}

class perlin {
public:
    perlin() {
        ranvec = new vec3[point_count];

        for (int i = 0; i < point_count; ++i) {
            ranvec[i] = unit_vector(vec3::random(-1, 1));
        }

        perm_x = perlin_generate_perm();
        perm_y = perlin_generate_perm();
        perm_z = perlin_generate_perm();
    }

    ~perlin() {
        delete[] ranvec;
        delete[] perm_x;
        delete[] perm_y;
        delete[] perm_z;
    }

    double noise(const point3 p) const{
        auto u = p.x() - floor(p.x());
        auto v = p.y() - floor(p.y());
        auto w = p.z() - floor(p.z());
        int i = floor(p.x());
        int j = floor(p.y());
        int k = floor(p.z());
        vec3 c[2][2][2];

        for (int di = 0; di < 2; di++)
            for (int dj = 0; dj < 2; dj++)
                for (int dk = 0; dk < 2; dk++)
                    c[di][dj][dk] = ranvec[
                        perm_x[(i + di) & 255] ^
                            perm_y[(j + dj) & 255] ^
                            perm_z[(k + dk) & 255]
                    ];

        return perlin_interp(c, u, v, w); //problem area
    }


private:
    vec3* ranvec;
    static const int point_count = 256;
    double* ranfloat;
    int* perm_x;
    int* perm_y;
    int* perm_z;

    static int* perlin_generate_perm() {
        auto p = new int[point_count];

        for (int i = 0; i < perlin::point_count; i++)
            p[i] = i;

        permute(p, point_count);

        return p;
    }

    static void permute(int* p, int n) {
        for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int target = random_int(0, i);
            int tmp = p[i];
            p[i] = p[target];
            p[target] = tmp;
        }
    }

    inline double perlin_interp(vec3 c[2][2][2], double u, double v, double w) {
        auto uu = u * u*(3 - 2 * u);
        auto vv = v * v*(3 - 2 * v);
        auto ww = w * w*(3 - 2 * w);
        auto accum = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                    vec3 weight_v(u - i, v - j, w - k);
                    accum += (i*uu + (1 - i)*(1 - uu))
                        * (j*vv + (1 - j)*(1 - vv))
                        * (k*ww + (1 - k)*(1 - ww))
                        * dot(c[i][j][k], weight_v);
                }

        return accum;
    }

};
```

Comment: You are trying to call `perlin_interp`, which is not available from a `const` `perlin` object. You can simply add `const` to its function definition, same as it's done in `noise`

Comment: `inline double perlin_interp(vec3 c[2][2][2], double u, double v, double w)` -> `double perlin_interp(vec3 c[2][2][2], double u, double v, double w) const`. `inline` is unnecessary here. All methods fully defined inside the class definition are `inline`.

Comment: Unrelated: Watch out for [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If a `perlin` is copied, the program will break.